# React: setState method not updating useState

Tags: reactjs

Description: I've got a list of open Bills on a React Data Table I'm trying to export to csv. I've made it so that the export button only displays if the `allBills` useState is not empty. However, when I click on a customer that has open bills in their name, the export icon is invisible, indicating the open bill list is empty (even though I'm looking at the open bills in the table).

Here's a bit of what the open bills modal looks like:

```
const fields = {
  "billMonth": "Bill Month",
  "amount": "Amount",
  "dateOfBillCreated": "Date Created",
  "createdBy": "createdBy",
  "remainingFee": "remainingFee",
}

const OpenBillModal = ({selectedUser}) => {
    const [billsLoader, setLoader] = useState(false)
    const [allBillsMeter, setAllBillsMeter] = useState([])
    const { saveAsCsv } = useJsonToCsv();

    useEffect(() =>{
        reload()
    },[selectedUser])

    const reload = () => {
        setLoader(true)
        const projectId = localStorage.getItem('projectId')

        projectId && getAHHOpenBillsMeter(prId, selectedUser.id).then(billsMeter => {
            setLoader(false)
            let _billsMeter = [...prepareBills(billsMeter)]
            setAllBillsMeter([..._billsMeter])
        })
    }   

    const prepareBills = (billsMeter) => {
        const bills = []
        // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
        billsMeter.map((bill) => {
            bills.push({
                "billMonth": bill.billMonth,
                "amount": bill.amount,
                "dateOfBillCreated": formatDate(getDateTimeFromSeconds((bill.dateOfBillCreated).seconds)),
                "createdBy": bill.createdBy,
                "remainingFee": bill.remainingFee,
            })  
        })

        return bills
    }

    const formatDate = (d) => {
        const ye = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(d);
        const mo = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' }).format(d);
        const da = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(d);
        return `${da}-${mo}-${ye}`
    } 
    const paymetnCol = [
        {
            name: 'Bill Month',
            selector: 'billMonth',
            sortable: true,
            minWidth: "60px"
        },
        {
            name: 'Amount',
            selector: 'amount',
            sortable: true,
            center: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Date Created',
            selector: 'dateOfBillCreated',
            sortable: true,
            format: (bill) => bill.dateOfBillCreated
        },
        {
            name: 'Created By',
            selector: 'createdBy',
            sortable: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'Remaining Fee',
            selector: 'remainingFee',
            sortable: true,
        }
    ]
    const generateCsv = () => {
        const da = { data: [...allBillsMeter], fields, 
            filename: `open_bills_${selectedUser.ownerName}`  }
        saveAsCsv(da)
    }
    
    const actionsMemoExportOpenBills = useMemo(
        () => (
                <div style={{width:"fit-content", height:"fit-content", left:"16px"}}>
                    { 
                        allBillsMeter && allBillsMeter.length > 0 && 
                        <img onClick={generateCsv} style={{cursor: "pointer"}} alt="excel_download" src={require("assets/img/excel.svg")}   width="25px" height="25px"/>
                    }
                </div>
            ),
        []
    )

    return ( 
        <div className="content"  style={{width: "100%", height:"100%", justifyContent:"center", alignContent:"center"}}  >
            <DataTable
                title="Open Bills"
                pagination={true}
                paginationPerPage={10}
                columns={paymetnCol}
                paginationComponentOptions={{ noRowsPerPage: true }}
                data={allBillsMeter}
                actions={actionsMemoExportOpenBills}
                progressPending={billsLoader}
                dense
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

My attempt: I've placed a debugger and seen that `setAllBillsMeter` is not being initialized with an empty array. I'm using deconstructors whenever I set one array with another like several answers online suggest. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get data when consoling the `allBillsMeter`?

Comment: Yes. That's the interesting part. I debugged and saw the result -- the same result I'm looking at on the table. But after the setAllBillsMeter statement, the useState hasn't changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the dependencies into the dependency array of the useMemo function. The blank array at the end of the `actionsMemoExportOpenBills` function should instead be `[allBillsMeter]`

Comment: It works.

Before that, I placed a debugger just below the `setAllBillsMeter` statement and saw the value of allBillsMeter value to be empty. I don't know why the **useMemo** made it work.